# Is this the same code for python dictionary?

Tags: python

If D is a python dictionary, are these two lines the same thing?

```
if d in D:
```

VS:

```
if d in D.keys():
```

I am reading other people' code and found these two lines in very close locations. I think they should be the the same and should be changed to the first version. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is the same but they aren't the same thing.
One can add iterators for custom classes by defining `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods, allowing syntax like `for x in costomContainer:`

1. `for key in dict:`
   Here dictionary defines its own implementation of `__iter__()` and `__next__()` - to iterate over the dictionary keys.
2. `for key in dict.keys():`
   `dict.keys()` returns a special object of type `dict_keys`, which defines its own `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods for interation.

Found a Python Enhancement Proposals  (PEP) document describing expectation with `dict.keys()` in more details:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/

Answer (score 1):

The first one is faster (since it doesn’t build an traverse a list of keys), but they produce the same result, yes.